App Crash when using ReactNativeFile in apollo upload client to upload file
Issue Description
I’m encountering a ClassNotFoundException related to okhttp3.internal.Util while trying to upload a file using ReactNativeFile with apollo-upload-client. Additionally, when using a Blob instance instead, the backend receives a null file argument, although the file upload works correctly when tested with Postman.
Steps to Reproduce

Use DocumentPicker to select a document (e.g., PDF, DOC, DOCX, or image).
Convert the selected file’s URI to a Blob instance.
Create a File object with the Blob instance and attempt to upload it using uploadImageMutation from Apollo.

Using ReactNativeFile:
const handleDocumentSelection = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
      type: [
        DocumentPicker.types.pdf,
        DocumentPicker.types.doc,
        DocumentPicker.types.docx,
        DocumentPicker.types.images,
      ],
      copyTo:
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'cachesDirectory' : 'documentDirectory',
    });

    const uploadFile = async (fileUri, fileName, mimeType) => {
      const file = new ReactNativeFile({
        uri: fileUri,
        name: 'picture.jpg',
        type: mimeType
      });

      console.log('File object to be uploaded:', file);

      try {
        const { data } = await uploadImageMutation({
          variables: { file },
        });
        console.log('Upload response:', data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Upload error:', error);
      }
    };

    const { fileCopyUri, name, type } = res[0];
    uploadFile(fileCopyUri, name, type);
  } catch (err) {
    if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
      // Handle cancel
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  }
};

### Using Blob Instance:
const handleDocumentSelection = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await DocumentPicker.pick({
      type: [
        DocumentPicker.types.pdf,
        DocumentPicker.types.doc,
        DocumentPicker.types.docx,
        DocumentPicker.types.images,
      ],
      copyTo:
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'cachesDirectory' : 'documentDirectory',
    });

    const convertUriToBlob = async (uri, mimeType) => {
      const base64Data = await RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(uri, 'base64');
      const byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
      const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
      for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      return new Blob([byteArray], { type: mimeType });
    };

    const uploadFile = async (fileUri, fileName, mimeType) => {
      const fileBlob = await convertUriToBlob(fileUri, mimeType);

      // Create a file object with a Blob instance
      const file = new File([fileBlob], fileName, { type: mimeType });

      console.log('File object to be uploaded:', file);

      try {
        const { data } = await uploadImageMutation({
          variables: { file },
        });
        console.log('Upload response:', data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Upload error:', error);
      }
    };

    const { fileCopyUri, name, type } = res[0];
    uploadFile(fileCopyUri, name, type);
  } catch (err) {
    if (DocumentPicker.isCancel(err)) {
      // Handle cancel
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  }
};

### Crash Log

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"okhttp3.internal.Util" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/~~6kd2JTp1gbPoLfrIrCABCA==/care.heyme.mobile-MkqSROqHXIAMbKVAbAvP-w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~6kd2JTp1gbPoLfrIrCABCA==/care.heyme.mobile-MkqSROqHXIAMbKVAbAvP-w==/lib/arm64,
/data/app/~~6kd2JTp1gbPoLfrIrCABCA==/care.heyme.mobile-MkqSROqHXIAMbKVAbAvP-w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product_h/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]

System Information
macOS: 14.1.1
Node: 16.0.0
npm: 7.10.0
React Native: 0.68.1
Apollo Upload Client: 11.0.0
Android SDK: API Levels 30, 31, 33, 34, 35
Android Studio: 2024.1
Java: 17.0.11
### Additional Information
The problem persists despite using the latest version of apollo-upload-client.
The backend receives a null file argument when using the Blob instance, but the upload works correctly in Postman.
Request for Help
Can anyone assist with resolving this issue? Are there known compatibility problems or configuration settings that could address this ClassNotFoundException and the issue with the Blob instance?
Reproduction Steps

Use DocumentPicker to select a document (e.g., PDF, DOC, DOCX, or image).
Convert the selected file’s URI to a Blob instance.
Create a File object with the Blob instance and attempt to upload it using uploadImageMutation from Apollo.

@apollo/client version
3.8.7

None of the code you supplied has anything to do with the crash happening. The crash is happening because your dependencies are missing or the references are not all pointing to the same version. Re-read the error.

all dependencies are installed the crash happen when calling uploadImageMutation and passing file object

Show us where you import okhttp3.internal.Util.

its weird that i didn't import okhttp3.internal.Util in the whole project (perhaps ReactNativeFlipper use it ) :p

Solution :
1/ need to implement Okhttp in app/build.gradle :
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.8.0'

2/ also force use this version: 3.8.0 in android/build.gradle like this :
allprojects {
     configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
            force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.8.0'
        }
    }
}

